# How to cache or store in project folder JSON object returned from $http call response? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I write Google Chrome extension and now I need to cache or store in project folder JSON object returned from $http call response. I'm using clear AngularJS without server.

I tried to use this solution: https://coderwall.com/p/40axlq/power-up-angular-s-http-service-with-caching, but I don't have Server (I don't need in it)

Controller (see the first get request):

```
var deliveryApp = angular.module('deliveryApp', []);

deliveryApp.controller('optimalDuration', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('https://tk-kit.ru/API.1/?f=get_city_list').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.citiesTkKit = data;
    // var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)],  {type: 'text/json'});
    // saveAs(blob, 'testFile.json');
    });

    $scope.info_show = '';
    $scope.save = function (form) {
    $scope.info_show = null;
    $http.get('https://tk-kit.ru/API.1/?f=price_order&WEIGHT=' + $scope.weight + '&LENGTH=' + $scope.length + '&WIDTH=' +
        $scope.wiidth + '&HEIGHT=' + $scope.heeight + '&SZONE=' + $scope.selected_city_from + '&RZONE=' + $scope.selected_city_to +
        '&PRICE=' + $scope.price)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.info_show = 'Доставим ваш груз за ' + data['DAYS'] + ' суток. С уважением, транспортная компания tk-kit!';
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}]);
```

I also tried to use FileSaver.js and commented part of code higher works, but save file only in the browser downloads folder...

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<form name="sendForm" ng-submit="save($element.action)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search1" placeholder="Введите город">
    <select name="cityFrom" ng-model="selected_city_from">
        <option ng-repeat="city in citiesTkKit['CITY'] | filter:search1" value="{{city['TZONEID']}}">{{city['NAME']}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search2" placeholder="Введите город">
    <select name="cityTo" ng-model="selected_city_to">
        <option ng-repeat="city in citiesTkKit['CITY'] | filter:search2" value="{{city['TZONEID']}}">{{city['NAME']}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <input type="text" ng-model="weight" placeholder="Вес товара в кг.">
    <input type="text" ng-model="length" placeholder="Длина товара">
    <input type="text" ng-model="wiidth" placeholder="Ширина">
    <input type="text" ng-model="heeight" placeholder="Высота">
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" placeholder="Объявленная стоимость груза">
    <button type="submit">Вычислить оптимальное время</button>
</form>

<h5>{{info_show}}</h5>
</div>
```

The main problem is that I need to wait 5-7 seconds to see options in my SELECT lists and I want to speed up this process.

**UPD** *I found the root of my problem. Converting to file and downloading JSON data which I receive from get-request, and then creating new get-request with another url (file path yet), my SELECT lists loaded is less than a second. But I can't download this file to my project folder because of browser security restrictions. I tried to include response JSON to localStorage: 
`localStorage.setItem('cities', citiesJSON)` But it has the same problem, too long time :( How can I store my response JSON data to speed-up my process?*

Comment: your speed issue is unrelated to chrome storage or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions have a [Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) that can store data locally within the browser or sync it across a user's Google account.

You'll need to ask for permission to `storage` in your manifest.

```
"permissions": [
    "storage"
],
```

You can then sync data to it:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    message('Settings saved');
});
```

Comment: I found the root of my problem. Converting to file and downloading JSON data which I receive from get-request, and then creating new get-request with another url (file path yet), my SELECT lists loaded is less than a second. But I can't download this file to my project folder because of browser security restrictions.
I tried to include response JSON to localStorage: `localStorage.setItem('cities', citiesJSON)` But it has the same problem, too long time :(
How can I store my response JSON data to chrome.storage to speed-up my process? Maybe you know another solutions? help please

Comment: If the element is collapsed by default, you need to show only one value at page initialization to make it appear instantaneous, so simply store that single value separately from the big complete list.